# Apache Phoenix: Using MINUS throws an error

Tags: query, hadoop

I'm using Apache Phoenix to query Hbase. I tried to use a simple MINUS operator like we do in good old SQL but it produces an error that I couldn't wrap my head 
around.

Here's the query:

```
select * from NOTIFICATION MINUS select * from NOTIFICATION where SUBJECT = 'datanode';
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

> Note: It's not this specific query I'm looking to solve, I just want
>   to get MINUS to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which SQL is used by Apache Phoenix and I cannot exclude that your code above contains syntax error but what I know is that the MINUS operator can only be used in Oracle SQL.

I suggest trying it with the EXCEPT operator which is used in Transact SQL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

If the EXCEPT does also not work, try to imitate the MINUS like it is done in MySQL, which currently does not feature MINUS or EXCEPT at all:
http://www.gokhanatil.com/2010/10/minus-and-intersect-in-mysql.html